# Comprehension - Nested if-conditions in Haskell

Tags: haskell

i try to become familiar with the if-condition statements in haskell

assume that i´ve an argument x and i try the following in haskell

```
functionname x = if x > 0 then x-5
                          if x-5 == 0 then 1
                          else if x-5 /= 0 then functionname x-5
                          else if x-5 <  then 0
```

so, the idea was to subtract 5 from x, check if the result is 0, if yes, then give a 1.
If not then invoke the function again with the expression x-5.
If the result of x-5 is negative then give a 0.

so, my questions: Would that be correct? Because when i try that, i´ve got a message like parse error on input 'functionname'.

how can i fix that problem? Are the if-else conditions wrong ?

---

```
programm :: Int -> Bool

programm x |  x > 0 =
   if z == 0 then True
   else if z < 0 then False
   else programm z
   where
   z = z-2

programm x |  x < 0 =
   if z == 0 then True
   else if z > 0 then False
   else programm z
   where
   z = z+2
```

so, i wanted to have the possibility to decide of a given number is even. So, i modify your solution a little bit. its the same but, at the beginning of the two declarations i said : x > 0 = ....  and x < 0 =... 
Because i want to say that for example -4 is also even. for that reason: the first declarations should handle the positive even numbers and the second declarations handles the negative even numbers.

when i give that to the compiler, then the message : Exception  appears. Where i ve made the mistake?

Comment: Unlike in some other languages, every `if` in Haskell needs an `else`.

Answer (score 4):

Use guards to make things clear:

```
functionname x
  | x > 0      = x - 5
  | x - 5 == 0 = 1
  | x - 5 /= 0 = functionname (x - 5)
  | x - 5 < 0  = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when i do that, then the compiler complain that the result from the first line (| x > 0      = x - 5) should be a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Every `if` needs to have an `else` clause associated with it.

The very first one doesn't and the very last one doesn't either.
This works just fine:

```
functionname x = if x > 0 then x-5
                 else if x-5 == 0 then 1
                 else if x-5 /= 0 then functionname x-5
                 else if x-5 < 0 then 0 else 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when i do that, then the compiler complain that the result from the first line (| x > 0 = x - 5) should be a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

> so, the idea was to subtract 5 from x, check if the result is 0, if
>   yes, then give a 1. If not then invoke the function again with the
>   expression x-5. If the result of x-5 is negative then give a 0.

That might be written like this:

```
functionname x =
    if x' == 0 then 1
    else if x' < 0 then 0
    else functionname x'
    where
    x' = x - 5
```

Here, I use a `where` clause to locally define `x'` as `x - 5` and then use it for the tests and the recursive call. Your first branch, `if x > 0 then x-5`, does not appear in your description of what function should do (it gives `x - 5` results as result whenever x is larger than zero, which is probably not what you want). Also, note that every `if` needs an `else` as well as a `then`.

> so, i wanted to have the possibility to decide of a given number is
>   even. So, i modify your solution a little bit. its the same but, at
>   the beginning of the two declarations i said : x > 0 = .... and x < 0
>   =... Because i want to say that for example -4 is also even. for that reason: the first declarations should handle the positive even numbers
>   and the second declarations handles the negative even numbers.

First of all, in the second version of your function the definition in the `where` clause should be `z = x + 2`, as `z = z + 2` will not terminate. This being an evenness test, you also want to perform the tests on `x` rather than `z`. With that fixed, your solution with nested conditionals should work fine (note, however, that you are not treating the `x == 0` case; the first guard should be `x >= 0`). There is a more elegant way of writing the function, though:

```
myEven :: Int -> Bool
myEven x = myEven' (abs x)
    where
    myEven' x
        | x == 0    = True
        | x < 0     = False
        | otherwise = myEven' (x - 2)
```

`abs` is the familiar absolute value function, while `myEven'` amounts to the `x > 0` branch of your original definition. Taking the absolute value of `x` is the easiest way to avoid writing two nearly equal branches to handle the negative and non-negative cases.

N.B.: While this is probably just a learning exercise, if you ever need to find whether a number is even there is an `even` function available from the Prelude. There is also `mod` if you need to test divisibility for other numbers.

Comment: @user3097712 I updated the answer to match the edited question.